# How to deal with duplicate child routes in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, router

I’m working on a project where I want to show two components (ProductionPlot & RnpPlot) within different routes. This is my index.js file  in router folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import ProductionPlots from '@/components/ProductionPlots'
import RnpPlots from '@/components/RnpPlots'
import Lessons from '@/components/Lessons'
import LessonOne from '@/components/AllLessons/LessonOne'
import LessonTwo from '@/components/AllLessons/LessonTwo'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Lessons',
      component: Lessons
    },
    {
      path: '/lesson-one',
      name: 'LessonOne',
      component: LessonOne,
      redirect: { name: 'ProductionPlots'},
      children: [
        { path: 'production-plot', name: 'ProductionPlots', component: ProductionPlots },
        { path: 'rta-plot', name: 'RnpPlots', component: RnpPlots }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/lesson-two',
      name: 'LessonTwo',
      component: LessonTwo,
      redirect: { name: 'ProductionPlots'},
      children: [
        { path: 'production-plot', name: 'ProductionPlots', component: ProductionPlots },
        { path: 'rta-plot', name: 'RnpPlots', component: RnpPlots }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

But I got the following warning in the console:

*[vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition: { name: "ProductionPlots", path: "/lesson-two/production-plot" }
[vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition: { name: "RnpPlots", path: "/lesson-two/rta-plot" }*

when I click on the second route (/lesson-two/production-plot), the first route  (/lesson-one/production-plot)  will be shown.

How I can resolve this? Please help me as I could not find this issue on stackoverflow or google.

Thank you,

Hassan

Comment: You are showing same component on each route `lesson-one` and `lesson-two`.. with same name.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the "name" on each child route. For example, I have two routes that both a have child route of "batteries". For the `name` on one of them, I used "product-batteries" and left the other as just "batteries", like so:

```
path: 'batteries',
name: 'product-batteries',
component: ProductBatteries
```

```
path: 'batteries',
name: 'batteries',
component: Batteries
```

Then when using `router-link`, you just call which name to use.